# Save list in mongodb using grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

i m new to mongodb so a little confused on how do i save the list object in mongodb using grails, basically i have a list of hasmap , which is in turn is a string,list map , like this

```
List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>> changedProperties = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>>()
```

and here is my domain class that have this type of property

```
class DatabaseEvent {

String type
String entityClass
String objectId
Date dateCreated
User loggedInUser
List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>> changedProperties
}
```

if i simply pass this type of list , it is not saving.

```
[[description:[null, some test]], [name:[Testing 12, Testing 1]], [displayOrder:[4, 11]]]
```

i m passing the above list , but it rejects with this error

```
rejected value [[{description=[null, some test]}, {name=[Testing 12, Testing 1]}, {displayOrder=[4, 11]}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.

**Grails in the Land of MongoDB**

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/18510469058/grails-in-the-land-of-mongodb